# Reload part of the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, reload

Please, help me!

Can you explain me how to reload **part** of the page WITH **change URL**, but it must **will not including hash tag**.

some code:  
URL: mysite.com/**first/**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>RELOAD!</h1>
  <div>few words...</div>
  <input type="button">
 <body>
</html>
```

want change to: 
URL: mysite.com/**second/**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>RELOAD!</h1>
  <div>other few words...</div>
  <input type="button">
 <body>
</html>
```

How I can do reload content only in DIV on another?

I was see one more examples, like this next:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1)
    location.assign(location.href.replace('#', "/"));
```

**BUT - it reload all page!**

**.htaccess** - I cannot use, 'cause char "#" and next text **not to sent to the server**.

Also I have seen code:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
}
else {
    location.hash = '#myhash';
}
```

but cannot understand it right.

**Maybe there is an other right way how to do it.**

Comment: Nope. No other way. `pushState` is the way to do it. Better start understanding it. :)

Comment: The documentation isn't under the term pushState its actually part of the history object. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two different problems here:

1. How to load content from the server and display it in the existing page, without reloading the whole page
2. How to make it look like you are on a new URL, without reloading the page

Neither of these have anything to do with `.htaccess` (by which is generally meant Apache's `mod_rewrite` module) because they are both about how the *client* is behaving, not the *server*.

The first part is generally referred to as "AJAX", about which you will find tons of information online. The "X" originally stood for "XML", but actually you can fetch whatever kind of data you want, such as plain text, or a piece of ready-made HTML, and use JavaScript to put it into place on your page. The popular jQuery library has [a method called `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which makes a request to the server, and uses the response to replace a particular part of the page.

The second part is a little trickier - since the page hasn't actually been reloaded, you essentially want the browser to lie about the current URL. The reason you will see a lot of examples changing only parts of the URL after the `#` is precisely because these aren't sent to the server; traditionally, they're used to scroll the current page to a paticular "anchor". You can therefore change them as often as you like, and if the user bookmarks or shares your page, you can look at the part after the `#` and re-load the state they bookmarked/shared.

However, as part of the "HTML5" group of technologies, an ability was added to change the actual URL bar of the browser, by "pushing a state" to the `history` object. In other words, adding an entry to the back/forward menu of the browser, without actually loading a new page. There are obvious security restrictions (you can't pretend the user navigated to a completely different domain), but the API itself is quite simple. [Here is the MDN documentation explaining it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

For your simple example, assuming jQuery has been included, you might do something like this:

```
// Find the div with a jQuery selector; this would be more specific in reality
jQuery('div')
    // Request some text from the server to replace the div
    .load(
        // This URL can be anything that generates the appropriate HTML
        '/ajax.php?mode=div-content&stage=second',

        // Add a callback function for when the AJAX call has finished
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            // Inside the callback function, set the browser's URL bar
            // and history to pretend this is a new page
            history.pushState({}, '', '/second/');
    }
);
```

Note that jQuery is far from the only way of doing this, it just keeps the example simple to make use of an existing function that does a lot of the work for us.

Comment: Well, thank you... But what about time... If my data will refresh, and in cash is saving old version - I will always get old data? Or what?

Comment: @serge I'm not sure what you mean. If the user hits "refresh", their browser should load the URL in the address bar, which will be your "second" page, and can render the content appropriately. The AJAX request could also be cached, based on the HTTP caching headers you set (just as with any other page or resource).

Comment: if I will do the next action: `history.pushState({page:

Comment: @serge I'm guessing you tried to put a newline in that comment. SO eats your text if you do that... :|

Comment: sorry, I had problem with internet yesterday. And if I will write - history.pushState({page: "http : //mysite.com/first", type: "page"}, document.title, "http : //mysite.com/first"); ... and reload my PC, will I have then this cache?

Comment: @serge Browsers cache responses from a server, not pages displayed to the user. If the real page loaded was `'/first/'`, and you use `history.pushState` to set the URL to `'/second/'`, then `'/second/'` will not be in the browser's cache, as you never actually loaded it from a server (you told the browser to lie). `'/first/'` will be in the cache for as long as the headers you send say it should be, just as if no JS had run on it at all, and the AJAX request you used to change the page might also be cached. Does that answer your question?

Comment: uh, so now, I know more, thank you before that, but  I cannot right understand you in the next: `"Browsers cache responses from a server"` how? As I know, cache saving in client PC, not server. Can you talk few words about it. And `"as the headers you send say it should be"` - WHERE me need say it? And third - if I **NO** use JS how `"the page might also be cached"` it can be, I really cannot understand! Sorry me, before many questions, but you say so interesting moments!

Comment: @serge HTTP consists of a series of requests from a client (the browser), and responses from a server, based mostly on the URL accessed. A request & response doesn't necessarily mean a page displayed in the browser, it could be an image, or an AJAX request. The browser caches individual responses, not whole displayed pages. Additionally, servers can send with any response "headers" with instructions like "don't cache this one" or "cache this one for 5 days".